# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to GET_NEW_EVENTS in Java

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, oracle10g

I'm getting the below error while calling a stored procedure from Java:

**"java.sql.SQLException: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_NEW_EVENTS'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored"**

The stored procedure is as below:

```
    create or replace package body event_subscription as
    procedure get_new_events( p_events in out SYS_REFCURSOR ) as
    begin
        open p_events for
            select log_id from event_alert_log;         
    end get_new_events;
end event_subscription;
```

And the Java code to cal the stored procedure is as below:

```
    sqlString = "BEGIN event_subscription.get_new_events(?); END;";
CallableStatement  cs = connection.prepareCall(sqlString);
cs.registerOutParameter(1,OracleTypes.CURSOR);
cs.execute(); // This line is failing and throwing the SQLException
ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(1);
```

The Oracle Version is: Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Product
The Java version is: 1.6.

Can somebody help me in this issue. I have been trying all possible solutions to this problem.

Comment: Is there a reason why your stored procedure parameter is declared `IN OUT`?  Does it help if you declare your stored procedure's parameter as `OUT` instead of `IN OUT`?  No value is being passed in for the cursor, so it makes sense to me to declare it `OUT` rather than `IN OUT`.

Comment: Hey Luke, Yeah, it was not intended to be IN OUT. But I was trying different options and during that time, I made it IN OUT. But I get the error even when I make it OUT alone.

Comment: Are you using the JDBC-ODBC bridge driver to connect to Oracle?  (The 'ODBC' in your error message suggests you might be doing this.)  If so, do you get the same problem if you use the Oracle JDBC driver?

Answer (score 1):

Odd.  I can't reproduce this.  I'm using Oracle XE 11.2.0.2.0 on Windows 7 x64, with version 11.2.0.2.0 of `ojdbc6.jar`.

I don't have your tables, so instead I queried a data dictionary view.  I created the following package

```sql
create or replace package event_subscription as
   procedure get_new_events( p_events out SYS_REFCURSOR );
end;

create or replace package body event_subscription as
    procedure get_new_events( p_events out SYS_REFCURSOR )
    as
    begin
        open p_events for
            select object_name, object_type from all_objects where rownum <= 10;
    end get_new_events;
end event_subscription;
```

and compiled the following Java class:

```java
import java.sql.*;

public class So12751878 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver();
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "user", "password");
        String sqlString = "BEGIN event_subscription.get_new_events(?); END;";
        CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall(sqlString);
        cs.registerOutParameter(1, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        cs.execute();
        ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(1);
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("Got '" + rs.getString(1) + "' and '" + rs.getString(2) + "'.");
        }
    }
}
```

This ran successfully.  It also ran successfully if I changed the stored procedure's parameter from `OUT` to `IN OUT`.

**EDIT**: you've now clarified in your comment that you're using the JDBC-ODBC bridge driver to connect to Oracle.  However, you're registering the type of the parameter as `oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR`.  This type is specific to the Oracle JDBC driver, and therefore not something I would expect the JDBC-ODBC bridge driver to understand, given that it has to support multiple databases.

Moral of the story: don't use the JDBC-ODBC bridge driver to connect to Oracle if using `OracleTypes.*` constants.  Better still, don't use the JDBC-ODBC bridge driver to connect to Oracle.

Comment: Yeah, the code you posted works. The difference in my code is in getting the database connection object. I have used the method as: `         String mDriver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
         String mURL =  "jdbc:odbc:DSNName";
         Class.forName(mDriver);
         Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(mURL, "username", "password");`. This one is causing the **wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_NEW_EVENTS'** error

Comment: Thanks for the help. It was really helpful. I was using the JDBC-ODBC bridge because the input for my application was DataSourceName but not the tns entry or any connection string.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have an IN OUT parameter, so you must set the IN, for example:

```
cs.setInt(1, -2);
```

and then the outparameter you already have. Both.

```
cs.registerOutParameter(1,OracleTypes.CURSOR);
```

There's the problem you get having a cursor IN... that won't work as IN parameter. Are you really going to send a refcursor as parameter?

Comment: Its my wrong, I don't send any refcursor, but it due to i was trying different options. Even with only OUT, it fails.

Comment: What if you use "{ call event_subscription.get_new_events(?); }" in the callablestatement?

Comment: With "{ call event_subscription.get_new_events(?); }", the prepareCall throws an error saying "[Oracle][ODBC]Syntax error or access violation.". I removed the semicolonand executed as ""{ call event_subscription.get_new_events(?) }" but this crashes with below error: # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x61afe929, pid=7528, tid=9960
#
# JRE version: 6.0_31-b05
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.6-b01 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [oracommon11.dll+0x14e929]